How to use VBA to fill in the order according to the poker card dealing method
There is data in columns A, B, and C. You can use column A to calculate the total. There are tentatively 2120. Column C has been filled in with 001001-045001 in advance. The first 3 digits are the group number, the maximum is 45, and the last 3 digits are the serial number, all of which are 001. Each group The maximum serial number can reach (2120-1)\45=47, and the remainder 2120-1-45*47=4 is included in the last group, so the last group of serial numbers is 47+4=51, which is 045052. The filled-in string cannot be overwritten by VBA. , and cannot be reused by other blank spaces. The blank spaces are filled in in the same way as poker cards are dealt. The starting sequence number is 002, the first blank space in column C is 001002, the second blank space is 002002....to the fourth The forty-seventh blank space is 047002, the forty-eighth blank space is 001003, the forty-ninth blank space is 002003...and so on.
Sub FillGroups()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim groupCount As Long
    Dim groupSize As Long
    Dim currentGroup As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxGroup As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Find the column number of the last data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    'Find the last group of the first 3 digits of the 6-digit string, such as "045001"--> "045"
    maxGroup = "000"
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Left(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value, 3) > maxGroup Then
            maxGroup = Left(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    groupCount = CLng(maxGroup)
    
    
    ' Calculate the size of each group
    groupSize = (lastRow - 1) \ groupCount
    
' Syntax that requires insertion sort ++++++++++++++++++
End Sub

The red text in the picture is to achieve a balanced rotation method like the way poker cards are dealt.


enter link description here

You don't show any picture (with red text). Also, it's unclear what you're asking - all I see is a long list of requirements.

The picture has been put in, just the beginning part.

"You can use column A to calculate the total" is a bit confusing  - do you mean "count" not "total"?   Is the red text representing the values filled in by your macro?  The description of what you need is pretty confusing to me....

lastRow Is the total,Calculate the quantity that can be allocated to each group,
What I need help with is determining the string that should be filled in the blank space in column C.

Before running the code  - are there any gaps in the group number for the already-filled values in Col C?  If No, then the max group is just the count of existing values?

This might be close:
Sub FillGroups()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr, rng As Range, frm As String, done As Boolean
    Dim maxGroup As Long, maxSer As Long, grp As Long, ser As Long, grpser As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'ws.[E2:E2120].Copy ws.[C2]   '########### testing only
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow) 'range to be filled
    
    'Find the max group#
    maxGroup = ws.Evaluate("MAX(IFERROR(LEFT(" & rng.Address() & ",3)*1,0))")
    If maxGroup = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no usable values
    
    arr = rng.Value                     'read all values to array
    maxSer = UBound(arr, 1) \ maxGroup  'max serial number
    Debug.Print "MaxGroup:", maxGroup, "MaxSer:", maxSer
    ser = 2
    grp = 1
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)      'loop over array
        If Len(arr(i, 1)) = 0 Then   'cell had no value?
            arr(i, 1) = Format(grp, "000") & Format(ser, "000") 'fill value
            
            'set flag if at the end of the regular pattern
            If grp = maxGroup And ser = maxSer Then done = True
            
            If Not done Then
                grp = grp + 1           'next group
                If grp > maxGroup Then  'got to max group?
                    ser = ser + 1       'increment serial #
                    grp = 1             'reset group
                End If
            Else
                ser = ser + 1       'just increment serial #
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Font.Color = vbRed 'flag inserted values
    rng.NumberFormat = "@" 'Text
    rng.Value = arr        'add back values
End Sub


My remainder seems wrong in this program,and the remainder 2120-1-45*47=4 is included in the last group,The first column should be deducted from the total,Program works,it's almost perfect

Are you able to share a file with sample data (only need Col C and the last value in ColA.  Add a column showing how the completed colC should look.

https://ufile.io/geg78kan

See edits above to account for those final cells.  Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

I tried the new syntax, but it only cleared the original group numbers and did not fill in any sorting

Sorry I left in a line which was only for testing.  See commented line above.
